# ngIf not updating the view in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form and I'm getting data from JSON. It has radio buttons. In there if user clicks on 'For someone else' I want to show the extra fields (It's already rendering). If user clicks 'Me' I want to hide that extra field. I tried with ngIf here. But my view is not updating. Also I tried ngzone and settimeout options. But nothing works. This is a stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ubotkt

Can someone help me on this

Comment: If the extrafield boolean is deleted from there ,it's working. My problem is that ,I want to show the extra field based on the condition

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As a solution to your problem, you can do the following:

1. Take out extra fields from `app-form-control` to `app-form-main`
2. Use an `EventEmitter` in `app-form-control` to communicate between `app-form-control` and `app-form-main`.
3. That `EventEmitter` will be called, on `(change)` of radios. That will emit the currently checked radio's value/key/id.
4. Read that value/key/id in `app-form-main` and based on that show/hide respective extra fields.

I have created sample code from yours here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ubotkt-njmuf9).

**Original Answer (and actual issue)**

The approach you have used is very weird.

This is what's happening form your code:

1. `app-form-control` is created 3 times, each for: A title (*Who is this request for?*), A radio button (*Me*), A radio button (*For someone else*)
2. Now, the conditional output of `extendedFields` is related to each `app-form-control`.
3. So, when you click on `Me` radio, the console which you're seeing is coming from `Me`'s `app-form-control` and same happens with `For someone else`.
4. Now when you're clicking `For someone else`, the conditional flag `showExtraField` changes, but it changes only for `For someone else`'s `app-form-control`.
5. Now when you click `Me`, the conditional flag `shoeExtraField` changes, but it only changes for `Me`'s `app-form-control`. The conditional flag `showExtraField` of `For someone else`'s `app-form-control` stays as it is.
6. So, as the conditional flag doesn't change, it doesn't hide extra fields.

I would recommend you to change your approach of creating form-controls. Otherwise, it would be very difficult for you to track bugs/issues.

Comment: This is like a survey forms. I'm getting data from API in actual scenario and passing values to this. This works fine when creating forms. Can you please provide a solution for the current one

Comment: I have updated my answer with the approach you can use and code, too.

Answer (score 1):

Coderaizer, you need know what do you want to get. Seeing your code I think you want to get some like

```
{answer:...,answerExt:...}
```

Well, there are some errors in your code. (some one are conceptual errors)

Your ngOnInit in form-main component must take account when data has key and if this key is not repeat. As supouse you want to get the above data

```
ngOnInit() {
    const formContent: any = {};
    this.dataList.forEach(data => {
      //we check if the formContent has or not the property data.key
      if (data.key && !formContent[data.key])
      {
        formContent[data.key] = new FormControl(data.value);
      }
      //we check if the formContent has or not the property data.key+"Ext"
      if (data.extendedFields && !formContent[data.key+'Ext'])
        formContent[data.key+'Ext'] = new FormControl(data.extendedFields.value);

    });
    this.quizForm = new FormGroup(formContent);

  }
```

As we can have two controls (answer and answerExt), in your form-control-component, in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.control = this.parentForm.get(this.data.key);
    this.controlExt = this.parentForm.get(this.data.key+"Ext");
  }
```

then, your form-control-component.html can be like

```
<h3>{{data.title}}</h3>

  <label *ngIf="data.controlType == 'text'" [attr.for]="data.key">{{data.label}}</label>
  <input *ngIf="data.controlType == 'text'" [type]="data.type">

  <div *ngIf="data.controlType == 'radio'">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let opt of data.options">
      <label>
        <!--see that we use formControl-->
        <input style="margin-left: 5px;" [formControl]="control" type="radio"
          <!--I use "data.id"-->
          [name]="data.key" [value]="data.id"
          [id]="data.quizId"> {{opt.key}}
      </label>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <!--the "if" is simple data.id=control.value-->
  <div *ngIf="data.extendedFields && data.id==control.value">
      <ng-container>
        <label [attr.for]="data.key">{{data.extendedFields.text}}</label>
        <!--see that we use formControl-->
        <input *ngIf="data?.extendedFields.type == 'text'" [formControl]="controlExt">
      </ng-container>
  </div>
```

You can see work in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ubotkt-5pmxn8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-main%2Fform-main.component.ts)

NOTE:There're a lot of unnecesary code, and the "map" of data list is not clear, try to simply it. Therefore if you select an option that has not extendent fiels you're going has the value

Comment: Thank you very much @Eliseo for the explanation. Could you please show me the conceptual errors , I'm new to forms. Thanx again

Comment: @coderaizer, when we has a "normal" reactiveForm we use [formGroup] and formControlName, https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-associating-the-formgroup-model-and-view but if our "control" is in a separate component, we have two options: pass the form and the controlName or pass the control itself. If pass the form and the controlName, it's better, in a ngOnInit get the "control" (it'is the instruction this.control=this.parentForm.get(this.data.key), but then we use in our component [formControl] https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-3-registering-the-control-in-the-template

Comment: Well, if our form is complicate, we can have a component that receive a form, and the name of a formGroup (imagine tipical card-credit form). In this case we can in ngOnInit equal form=parentForm.get('card-credit') and use [formGroup]=form and formControlName. At last, when we use a JSON to create the form, this json is used 1.-to show the fields, 2.-to create the form

Answer (score 0):

You had the wrong bool value set it was true for me and false for someone else

```
if(evt.target.value == "Me"){
  this.showExtraField = false; //change this
}else if(evt.target.value == "For someone else") {
  this.showExtraField =true; //change this
}
```

Comment: You have provided the same answer. It's not working brother. Click Me again , then I need to hide that extra fields. It's not working

Comment: @coderaizer impressive code bro..Ive made a similar survey form builder with angular what you can do is use the ngOnChanges lifeCycle hook to listen to any changes in the input

Comment: You can check the answer that was checked and accordingly reset the showExtraField

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ubotkt-lghf9e This one is very crude ..but gets the job done

Comment: Do comment if it helped.

Comment: Give me a minute I'll check and let you know and I'll upvote

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure binding value to *ngIf should be Boolean , sometime in js , its converted to string , then *ngIf  won`t  work as expected .

my recommendation is cross check again by using typeof operator

Answer (score -1):

Simply nesting it into the options solved the problem.

```
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <h3>{{data.title}}</h3>

  <label *ngIf="data.controlType == 'text'" [attr.for]="data.key">{{data.label}}</label>
  <input *ngIf="data.controlType == 'text'" [type]="data.type">

  <!--Single Radio button view-->
  <div *ngIf="data.controlType == 'radio'">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let opt of data.options">
      <label>
        <input style="margin-left: 5px;" #radio (change)="handleChange($event)" type="radio" [name]="data.key" [value]="data.options['0'].value"
          [id]="data.quizId"> {{opt.key}}
      </label>
      <!--Extended field view-->
      <div *ngIf="data.extendedFields && data.extendedFields.type">
        <div *ngIf="data.extendedFields.type == 'text' && radio.checked">
          <ng-container>
            <label [attr.for]="data.key">{{data.extendedFields.text}}</label>
            <input *ngIf="data?.extendedFields.type == 'text'" [formControlName]="data.key">
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```